# reference from a newly created object

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [new operator and reference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732605/new-operator-and-reference-error)

In old version of php, I have to use an ampersand to reference newly created object such as

```
$a=&new something();
```

and I am running this old code in a newer version of php, I get warnings of deprecated use of references. If I delete all & from those warnings, I run into errors. Is there any way I can fix this without reinstalling old php to match the source I am using. I am grateful for any help and pointers.