# new operator and reference error

Tags: php, reference

```
 $class_name = 'MDB2_Statement_'.$this->phptype;
        $statement = null;
        $obj =& new $class_name($this, $statement, $positions, $query, $types, $result_types, $is_manip, $limit, $offset);
```

The above code is old, I would like to change it into something like

```
$class_name='MDB2_Statement_'.$this->phptype;
...
$obj_=new class_name($this, $statement, $positions, $query, $types, $result_types, $is_manip, $limit, $offset);
$obj=&$obj_;
```

But this doesn't result in correct behaviors. Could anyone offer me a fix ?

[**UPDATE**]
if i leave the old code as it is, I run into some "deprecated warnings" in every view page that is loaded

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs...\APPLI\php\library\PEAR\MDB2.php on
>   line 391

for example.

I open that file and would like to edit it in some way (I don't know) so as for the Deprecated to go away. The only current solution is to reinstall the XAMPP that contains appropriate PHP version to match the one the old was written in. I am at a loss as to figure out any way to deal with these warnings without any reinstallation, it is certain that I don't want to see those Deprecated on top of every page at all. Thank you.

Comment: PHP 5 and above has automatic assign by reference for objects. What warnings are you getting after removing the ampersand(&)

Comment: deprecated in file ......I am using 1.7.7 XAMPP's PHP

Comment: "deprecated in file" is the error you are getting? Highly unlikely!

Comment: I don't want to reinstall XAMPP to fit old stuff

Comment: You still haven't specified the error you are running into after you remove the ampersands(&) from your code.

Comment: Why do you want to change it? ("If it ain't broke, don't fix it"...)

Comment: What behavior *does* it result in and what *should* it result in?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you're missing the $ in front of class_name in the second version, I don't really see the difference..

Comment: I update to clearify it better.

Comment: Deja vu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732057/reference-from-a-newly-created-object

Answer (score 4):

The only thing PHP is complaining about is this:

```
$obj =& new $class_name...
      ^
```

You do not need and should not use *assignment by reference* anymore, since objects are always references in PHP 5. Just get rid of the `&`, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks, that is not really true, the old code I am using is for quite a pretty large project running for a local company's system that deals with DB a lot. I tried your method and it failed once. Now I need a new step by step reference to make it work.

Comment: What do you mean "objects are always references"? I can't copy an object into two variables are operate on them independently? EDIT: Holy crap, I never knew that: http://codepad.org/MdQ2T20C

Comment: @Mad There you go. To make a copy of an object, you explicitly need to `clone` it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create reference of an object in php 5.3.10 using this way.

```
$firstObj = new something();
$referenceObj = &$firstObj;
```

Comment: Or, you can just assign one variable to another, thus: `$referenceObj = $firstObj;`. As per @deceze in another answer here, you need to explicitly clone an object to get a non-reference copy.

Comment: When you use " $referenceObj = $firstObj; " Then $referenceObj can be assigned new values after this statement like this. " $referenceObj = null; " but when you create reference you can't do that because $referenceObj treats as Object.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm with you. I was underlining the point that, if you assign one variable as equal to another in either way, modifying the object via one variable will modify the other. I was making it clear to readers that the new assignment is not an independent copy `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even use the reference operator with objects?
A object is placed in the memory and all variables bound to it will change its memory.

In other words

```
$a1 = new stdClass;
$a2 = $a1;
```

would have the same affect as:

```
$a1 = 1000;
$a2 = &$a1;
```